# Machine Learning with Google Data

Tags: ruby, machine-learning, artificial-intelligence

A couple years ago I saw a fantastic presentation on machine learning based on using Google as the data source.  The idea was to leverage Google and Ruby to get more people involved in the concepts of machine learning since massive amounts of data are now readily accessible.  For the life of me I have not been able to find this presentation.  I realize that this wouldn't normally be a very good format to ask this question, however the content was so valuable and well presented that I felt we would all be enriched by having another pointer to this information.

Although I realize this is somewhat vague, Can anyone refer us to this original video presentation?

If not, could you share some useful links that would get one started down this road of machine learning leveraging massive data sources that now exist and are generally available?

Comment: Do you have any more details, like a conference name or location? Did you attend or view it online?

Comment: Boy for the life of me I cannot recall much more.  It was some kind of meetup I believe and I think the video of his presentation was on Vimeo as I vaguely recall the formatting of the site was not YouTube.  For some reason I want to say it was Avdi Grimm, but it was not.

Comment: http://www.igvita.com/2011/04/20/intuition-data-driven-machine-learning/ ?

Comment: YES!  It was Ilya Grigorik!!!  Thanks @AlptiginJalayr!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As was noted in the comments the link is: [Intuition & Data-Driven Machine Learning](http://www.igvita.com/2011/04/20/intuition-data-driven-machine-learning/)

He particularly piqued my interest with this quote: *"... **in certain cases, you are simply better off working on getting more data, then spending your time on improving the algorithm**..."*

Excellent presentation and presenter ([Ilya Grigorik](http://www.igvita.com))!  Highly recommended for anyone wanting to start down the path of machine learning.